# How to point to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pass-by-reference, argument-passing

I am writing a shader for OpenGL and I need to be able to pass in an array of data. I need to be able to pass by reference because I cannot copy the whole array. I know that you cannot define a pointer to an array of structs with `Vertices *v[100];` because this will create an array of pointers.

I think you can pass the memory location of the first element in the c array with `bindArrayFunction(&v);` but then how should I use it? Would I increase the pointer by the size of the struct to get every vertex?

Any help or comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C and C++, an array is *never* passed by value.

When an array type appears in a function declaration (as in `void f(int a[])`), the type is implicitly converted to the corresponding pointer type (as in `void f(int* a)`).

When you use the name of an array in most expressions, it is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element.  So, given `int v[100]`, when you call `f(v)`, a pointer to the initial element of `v` is passed.  (There are several exceptions to the implicit conversion, most notably when the array is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator).

Pointer arithmetic is always done in terms of the size of the pointed-to element.  So, given `v + 1`, the array `v` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its initial element (equivalent to `&v[0]`) and is incremented by `sizeof(int)` bytes, to point to `v[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

Just reference it as though it were an array.

```
void bindArrayFunction(Vertices *v, int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    process(v[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In most situation, an array **decays** to a pointer to its first element.  So if you have a function:

```
void foo(int *p)
{
    printf("%d\n", p[2]);
}
```

then these two calls are identical:

```
int array[10];

foo(array);
foo(&array[0]);
```

In both case, a single pointer is passed to the function, allowing the function to access the entire array.